# Evertime I press a button I want it to indicate when my textbox or textboxes are empty in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, button, textbox, progress-bar

Evertime I press a button I want it to indicate when my textbox or textboxes are empty. Because there's 3 and I need this error to come up **even** when one out of all is empty. If all textboxes are filled up I want my progress bar to start loading too. I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: can you provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please show your code and where it failed ...

Answer (score 1):

*create keydown event for all textboxes same, and call the function*

```
public void checkstatus()
{
if(textbox1.Text.Trim()=="" || textbox2.Text.Trim()=="" || textbox3.Text.Trim()=="")
{
 MessageBox.Show("Some Textboxes are empty");
}
else
{
 progessbar.Start();
}
```

}

Comment: Instead of `textbox1.Text.Trim()==""` you should use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox1.Text)` or if you want to allow whitespaces `string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text)`